# Tensorflow Predicting Sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, sequence

So my task is to predict sequence. I have x,y,z values at time t which are float type. I have to predict sequence that has values x,y,z at time (t + 1).

```
TIME_STEP = 10
N_FEATURES = N_CLASSES = 3
LEARNING_RATE = 0.01
EPOCHS = 50
BATCH_SIZE = 10

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None, N_FEATURES], name = 'name')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [N_CLASSES], name = 'labels')
```

then I have my lstm model, which looks like:

```
    x = tf.transpose(x, [1, 0])
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, num_features])

    hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, self.h_W) + self.h_biases)
    hidden = tf.split(hidden, self.time_step)

    lstm_layers = [tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(self.hidden_units, forget_bias=1.0) for _ in range(2)]

    lstm_layers = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(lstm_layers)
    outputs, _ = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(lstm_layers, hidden, dtype = tf.float32)

    lstm_output = outputs[-1]
```

and finally I define loss function and optimizer

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - y_pred))
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = LEARNING_RATE).minimize(loss)
```

for now I want to take previous 10 values to predict the 11th one. so I run session like

```
for time in range(0, len(X)):
        sess.run(opt, feed_dict = {x : X[time: time + TIME_STEP ],
                                   y : Y[time + TIME_STEP + 1]})
```

but when I check loss for this function it has huge value like 99400290.0 and it increases time by time. This is my first experience with predicting sequences so I think I must be missing something huge

Comment: Did you try decreasing the learning rate?

Comment: I've checked learning rate with 0.00001 but it still is not working.

Comment: What is the value range of x,y and z and does your last activation function reflect on that? For example if your network can only output values between 0 and 1 but should be able to predict 99, this would be a problem. It may be a good to normalize x, y and z in general.

Comment: You are right, values has huge variance they can be from -100 up to 163 000, I have used MinMaxScaler on X data but I have left my Y untouched, stupid mistake. Now I have tried applying it on test data as well and loss got 1e-7 and it started decreasing. Thank you for the comment but one question, MinMaxScaler is fit on some training cases and how should I normalize my input data when applying on real world problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should normalize your real world input data and it should use the same scaling (same parameters) that you used on your training set.

The reason is, now your model is trained to accept inputs of a certain shape and scale and for it to perform as intended you'll have to scale your test inputs to it.

(sorry for posting this as an answer, not enough rep for commenting)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, yes now I understand that, but can you offer any scaling algorithms that can work well on data that has variation from 0 to 300 000?

Comment: Well as far as I know Min-Max scaling and Standardization are the methods that are almost only used. There is another method called Normalization but it's only used for matrices.

The range it's spread out is not much of a problem when it comes to normalizing since that's kind of the whole point doing it. 

When the inputs are large they tend to output values that are in either ends of the activation function which makes it hard in back prop since gradients are almost 0. That's why we tend to use values from 0 to 1 or  -1 to 1.

Comment: I know about this normalization techniques. But when I fit my scaling function on training data I think I have to save it to normalize my input data that will correspond to training values. I've found the way to save the normalization from Sklearn library so I will go with that. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to save the values you used for normalizing like "μ" and "σ". Glad to help :)